# Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Normally, a Java p'rogram starts from an object, then that object will create some GUI objects (window) and call the "Show" method

So, is there any way to do the same thing in Android, since, by default in Android, a program runs from an object created by a class which extended from Activity class?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to emulate Swing on top of Android? The short story is that while it might be possible to do such a thing, it would be a very, very large amount of work.

The Android model has several advantages; it's much better in the long term to learn it and take advantage of its capabilities than to try to figure out ways to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there any way to do the same
>   thing in Android, since, by default in
>   Android, a program runs from an object
>   created by a class which extended from
>   Activity class?

No, sorry. Writing Android applications is a bit more like writing a servlet in that respect. When you write a servlet, you do not write a `main()` method, because what you are writing is really a plugin to a larger framework. Similarly, writing an Android application is really writing a series of plugins to a larger framework, so you do not write a `main()` method in Android, either.